# How can I receive multipart POST data requests in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

How can I receive multipart POST data requests in ASP.NET C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Markup:**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  Width="175"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="lblMsg" Visible="false" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

**Get a posted file in btnUpload_Click:**

```
HttpPostedFile File = FileUpload1.PostedFile;

int i = File.ContentLength;
byte[] Data = new byte[i + 1];

File.InputStream.Read(Data, 0, File.ContentLength);

string sFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File.FileName.Replace(" ", "_"));
string p = Server.MapPath("~/images/");

File.SaveAs(p + sFileName);
```

Answer (score 4):

The ASP.Net pipeline already handles this for you. It becomes part of the request object. It should be in the Request.Form dictionary.

Check:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx

If you're using files you have to look at HttpPostedFile to get all the files that were uploaded.

*Added*

Or the Request.Files collection...

Comment: the post is coming from a flash object that captures an image and sends via POST.

Comment: You should edit your initial question with that information. I had no idea where you were coming from.

Answer (score 2):

System.Web.HttpPostedFile and System.Web.HttpFileCollection